# How to stitch 4 images using opencv in c++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-stitching

I have images of 4 different positions of a road and I want to stitch them together using OpenCV. 
The problem is that the changes between the pictures is not "smooth", the color and the texture of the images is not the same so it doesn't seem like this is actually 1 big picture.

Comment: i would probably use imagemagick or just a photo processing program (read: photoshop, gimp) to stitch together images.

Comment: hmm... I need to do this using opencv. I thaught about histogram matching between the edges of the images, someone can help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out the [sticher class](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d1/d46/group__stitching.html) of opencv. Specially the examples examples opencv brings in the source code at `opencv_source_code/samples/cpp/stitching.cpp` and at `opencv_source_code/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp`.

If the result of executing the stiching example in your images is what you want you can explore the code to see how it was done.